Blank page after login to Microsoft account from other app
we are using Microsoft accounts in our company, we installed bitrix24 crm, now we are trying to connect calendar with microsoft calendar , after choosing the account , it shows a blank page, taking in account that we have added the redirect URL to app registration in Microsoft azure and marked a web app.
i tried to add redirect url in app registration in azure portal, and now getting blank popup
